# GitHub: Collating & organizing repositories

Tags: github

I am working on some projects now and storing code in GitHub.

I have split various components out into separate repos. The issue I'm having is that GutHub repos are a flat structure. So all the repos are jumbled together with all my other projects and their is no organization.

So, in a nutshell can I group repositories into a project? Maybe even group projects together? I tried creating a project in GitHub, but apparently repositories are outside projects.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to organise repos within a personal account or organization

Comment: Well that sucks! But confirms my suspicions. Thanks

Comment: An effective solution is to, on project creation to setup a GitHub page with links to the repos and even some brief documentation on each. Then the interface to my work is the project page and not the GitHub dashboard. Bonus points for forcing me create a basic document set!

Answer (score 1):

The common workaround seems to be the creation of project-specific accounts. For instance there is https://github.com/texstudio-org which groups several TexStudio-related repositories. When migrating to such a model, you could use the *Settings > Transfer Ownership* option.

It doesn't help though, that there is no compact view of the repositories with static sorting order.